# Installing smartgwt into local maven repository

Tags: maven, smartgwt

I am trying to install smartgwt, but didn't get a success:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file -Dfile=D:\smartgwt-4.0 -DgroupId=com.smartgwt -DartifactId=smartgwt -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath="c:\Users\user_name\.m2\"
```

smartgwt is located in d:\smartgwt-4.0\smartgwt.jar

Tell me please what my it fault?

Comment: What error do you have? file option should be `-Dfile=D:\smartgwt-4.0\smartgwt.jar`. Also `mvn install:install-file ...` should be sufficient

Comment: And -DlocalRepositoryPath is probably redundant, in any case it should be something such as `c:\Users\user_name\.m2\repository`

Comment: I know that it should be sufficient, but it shouldn't in my case. I put file options as you said, but it need pom.xml! If you see here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html you can see, it should be path to file, but not file path

Comment: sorry, orid, you're right! -Dfile must be as well as you said!

Answer (score 2):

Try using below command:

```
call mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -Dversion=4.0 -DgroupId=com.smartgwt -DartifactId=smartgwt -Dfile=D:\smartgwt-4.0\smartgwt.jar
```